# Logic behind not getting output while using Bitwise AND instead of AND Operator

Tags: python, bitwise-and

Can you give the clarity in Python

```
i = 2
if i<3 and i>1:
   print('its ok')
```

Output: 'its ok'     ------> no problem over here

But when I'm going to use Bitwise AND instead of AND, the code has been executed but nothing in output.

```
i = 2
if i<3 & i>1:
   print('its ok')
```

Output: nothing  ------> why ??

Comment: `and` and `&` have different precedence levels!  Your second example is being parsed as as `i < (3&i) > 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use bitwise AND (&) to perform logical AND (&&) operation!

It should be

```
if i<3 && i>1:
    print('its ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operate on numbers, but they treat them as if they were a string of bits, written in binary.

```py
a & b
```

The `&` operator returns 1 when the corresponding bits of both a and b are 1. Otherwise it returns 0.

If you use the && **logical** operator, it will work as you want it:

```py
i = 2

if i < 3 && i > 1: 
    print('Works!')
```

Answer (score 0):

`i<3 & 1>1` is read as `i<(3 & i)>1`.
`&` is the bitwise AND operator.

So, this evaluates to `i<(3 & 2)>1` which is equal to `i<2>1` .
`i` ( = 2) is not less than 2, so the first condition is `False`. Therefore, it fails the condition.